# Commercial Python IDE

Tags: software-development, python, ide

I believe that great value can be created in the pursuit of profit. Therefore I am interested in good commercial Python IDEs. Free-ware/nag-ware is considered commercial for my purposes.

Answers here should keep in mind the [original question asked on StackOverflow here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81584/541136) And also keep in mind the dimensions focusing on what it has, not what it doesn't.

This question seeks to be part of a collection of canonical questions on the matter. Look for another question asking for [Open Source IDEs here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/26147/910).

Answerers: please only post ***one*** IDE per answer. Please avoid screenshots, instead post a couple of links to their respective sites. See *Spyder* and *Emacs* as exemplary answers, in terms of brevity on [the Open Source question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/26147/910).

Voters: please vote based on the qualities of the IDE as opposed to the quality of the answer.

Comment: You don’t list any features/requirements besides that the IDE should be "good" and "commercial". This is too broad.

Comment: Do you honestly expect us to follow all the mentioned links to collect your requirements, so we might be able to recommend you something fitting your needs? While it's good to see you did some research, those might serve as references – but shouldn't *replace* your specifications. Please see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then [edit] your post to fill the gaps.

Answer (score 4):

## [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/#ide)

Important to note that typically for commercial purchases I believe companies might opt-in to getting IntelliJ instead as to unlock all languages supported by Jetbrains. This post, however, will focus on PyCharm prices & features only.

Subscription-based model starts November 2, 2015: *Full Details: https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/*

- Commercial: US $ 119 1st year, FREE 2nd year, US $ 119 3rd yr onwards
- Personal: US $53 1st year, FREE 2nd year, US $53 3rd yr onwards

Key Features -
Syntax highlighting, auto-Indentation and code formatting, code completion, line and block commenting, on-the-fly error highlighting, code snippets, code folding, unit-testing. [Full details](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/)

Answer (score 2):

### Wing Python IDE

My personal favourite is WingIDE from [WingWare](http://wingware.com/).

There are 3 editions/usage, (plus free trial), available, *pricing as at 2 Nov 2015*:

- Wing IDE Pro:

  - Commercial Use: $245 per **User** transferable and with bulk purchasing - *companies, paid individuals, organizations & government*.
  - Non-Commercial Use: $95 per **User**   *For students, educators, academic researchers, hobbyists & publicly funded charities*
  - Free Use: Free Licence - *Wingware grants free Wing IDE Pro licenses for classroom use and unpaid open source developers.*
- Wing IDE Personal *Omits some features*: $45 per **User**

then $89 per annum Support & Upgrades all the above, *with the possible exception of the free licences*.
Note that all the above licences are per user and may be installed on more than one machine for use by a single individual.

- Runs on OS X, Windows & Linux

### Editor Features

- Syntax highlights Python and 60+ languages
- Auto Completion
- Code Folding
- Line Numbers
- *Bookmarks*
- *Macros*
- *Auto Edit*
- Code Snippets
- User selectable key bindings:

  - Native
  - Vi/Vim
  - Emacs
  - Visual Studio
  - Eclipse
  - XCode
  - Brief
  - Custom
- Smart indentation and indent guides
- Adapts to file indent and EOL style
- Block commenting
- Rectangular and line selection
- Detect and load external changes
- Drag and lock editor splits & tabs
- Print file or selection
- Auto-save and restore

### Code Intelligence

- Goto-definition  Source index menus Auto-indent
- Converts indents and EOL on paste
- Code-aware line wrapping
- Error indicators
- Scans for sys.path changes in main debug file
- Auto-completion for Python and extension modules
- Quick keyboard navigation to files
- Find symbol in current file
- Enhanced auto-completion for PyQt, PySide, and wxPython
- Word list driven auto-completion for other file types
- Call tips & documentation (Source Assistant)
- Indentation translator
- *Class browser*
- *Module browser*
- *Current file browser*
- *Links into docs.python.org*
- *Find points of use*
- *Find symbol in project*
- *Refactoring*

### Debugger

- GUI, Web, and embedded debugging
- Exception traceback reporting
- View stack, locals/globals, and return value
- Integrated debug process I/O
- Native console I/O option
- Multi-threaded debugging
- Remote debugging inc Raspberry-Pi
- Debug value tooltips
- Detect unhandled exceptions
- Works with Django, web2py, Flask, Plone, and many others
- Remote debugging to Raspberry Pi
- Alter debug data values
- Interactive debug probe with code intelligence
- Multi-process debugging
- Automatic child process debugging
- Move Program Counter Convenient
- Restart Debugging tool
- Named Entry Points
- Launch Configurations
- Watch values and expressions
- Track values by reference
- Conditional breakpoints
- Ignore-counted breakpoints
- Enable/disable breakpoints
- Breakpoint manager
- Process attach/detach
- Inspect sys.modules
- Debug Django template files
- matplotlib mainloop support

### Unit Testing

- Select test files by pattern or name
- Execute tests and view results
- Debug tests
- Supports unittest style tests
- Supports pytest style tests
- Supports doctest style tests
- Supports nose style tests
- Supports Django tests
- Persists test results in the project
- Optional concurrent execution of tests
- Save/Load Test results
- Copy result summary to clipboard

### Revision Control

- Subversion integration
- CVS integration
- Mercurial integration
- Bazaar integration
- Git integration
- Perforce integration
- Diff/Merge tool

### Search Interfaces

- Basic search
- Toolbar quick search
- Search in Selection
- Keyboard-driven mini-search
- Project-wide search
- Regex and wild card search
- Search Wing IDE documentation
- Search on disk

### Project Manager

- Project creation by type
- Add files or directories Auto-updates with disk contents
- File management in project view
- Configure Python version and path
- Configure environment Line ending and indent policies
- Django project setup tools

### Other Features

- Integrated Python shell with code intelligence
- Customizable user interface layout and colors
- Create multiple tool instances
- Drag and drop tools and editors
- Graphical preferences editor
- Integrated documentation, How-Tos, and tutorial
- Supports most versions of CPython and ActivePython
- Supports Stackless Python
- Supports 32-bit and 64-bit Python builds
- Supports debug builds of Python Supports cygwin Python
- Supports code in zip archives and eggs
- Supports code in buildouts
- Supports virtualenv
- Integrated feedback / bug reporting
- Automatic patch / update manager
- French GUI Localization
- German GUI Localization
- PyLint integration
- OS commands tool Perspectives
- Extend IDE with Python scripting

*Disclaimer: I have **used** WingIDE for several years and paid for my licence but have other commercial relationship with the company.*

Answer (score 1):

[Enthought Canopy](https://store.enthought.com/#canopy-individual)

[Komodo IDE](http://komodoide.com/)

Although i prefer open source and have never used any of the above but these were recommended in the course i was taking at the MIT. Hope this helps..Best of Luck!!! Cheers!!

Comment: Good job on the brevity, but could you split this answer into two, with a really short description of each? Thanks!